# I want to write a logic in views.py and save data in serializer

Tags: python, django

I am making a system saved user data to model.I want to write a part of logic in views.py and a part of save data in serializer.I want to make a system password is changed into hash.Now I wrote codes in views.py,

```
class InfoViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def create(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = Info()
        passwd = request.data['password']

        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(passwd.encode('utf-8'))

        user.password = md5.hexdigest()

        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({"data":"data"})
```

in serializer.py

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = Info(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

in models.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
    username = custom_fields.NotEmptyCharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = custom_fields.NotEmptyCharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'info'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.username, self.email)
```

Now whenI tried to save user data to model,django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Can not be empty!'] error happens.What is wrong in my codes?I searched http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ .How should I fix this?

Comment: Off topic from your question, but you should absolutely not be using MD5 to hash passwords unless you are supporting a legacy system or have a very specific use-case. As @hammygoonan said you should be using the built-in django `User.set_password` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `InfoSerializer()` serializer so, remove `create()` method from that, and change your `views.py` as below,

```
class InfoViews(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = InfoSerializer(request.data).data
        serializer.pop('created_time', None)
        passwd = serializer['password']
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(passwd.encode('utf-8'))
        serializer['password'] = md5.hexdigest()
        Info.objects.create(**serializer)
        return JsonResponse({"data": "data"})
```

**My Friendly Suggestion**
I don't think this is a good method to acheive so, So changes below will do better (I think so ;))
**views.py**

```
class InfoViews(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

**serializer.py**

```
import hashlib


class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    def set_password(self, raw_pwd):
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(raw_pwd.encode('utf-8'))
        return md5.hexdigest()

    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = self.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

**Update**
Alternative `create()` for serializer,

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data['password'] = self.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user = Info.objects.create(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        username=validated_data['username'],
        password=validated_data['password']
    )
    # you can avoid large number of assignment statements (as above) by simply calling "super()" method

    return user
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have one question,why did you add super() of `super().create(validated_data)` in your serializer.py?

Comment: It would create and return an `Info` instance with provided `validated_data`. By using that, you can avoid `assignment statements`

Comment: look at the **Update** portion of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a validation error because `email` is a required field. When you run `user.save()`, the `email` value isn't sent, hence the `ValidationError`.

You should definitely be saving everything in your view, the Serialiser is just a way to change the way the data is presented by DRF.

Also, you really shouldn't be using md5 to save your passwords. Just use the built in Django method: `user.set_password(password)` - Django will take care of the hashing for you and much more securely.